# How to condense onclick code to be dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to get this onclick function code to be dynamic. I do not want to have 50 blocks of code for all the states. He is a quick snippet of the code

```
    var Ohio=function(){
    document.getElementById('texas').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('florida').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('ohio').style.display='block';

    }
```

and so on and so forth.....

the html that passes the function:

```
<li onclick="Ohio()" id="ohio" >
```

and so on and so forth
How would I go about condensing this to make it smaller and dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

If you can update the elements to have a common class, e.g., `class="state"`, then:

```
var SetState = function(state) {
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName("state"),
        i;
    for (i=0; i < s.length; i++)
        s[i].style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById(state).style.display = 'block';
};
```

That is, loop through all elements with the `state` class and hide them, then show just the one that was passed into the function with:

```
SetState('ohio');
```

Alternatively, if you can't change the html, put all the state names in an array and loop through the array to hide them.